# Ubuntu server hardware RAID 1 extension

Tags: server, raid, lvm

i am pretty new to servers configuration and i would like to ask you guys the following questions *knowing that i am planning to run ubuntu serer 18.04 on a dell poweredge, 2x1T SAS hdds physical RAID 1* :

1- Is it possible to have the /boot partition on the RAID partition  ?

2- Is it necessary to configure LVM over the RAID for to facilitate futur expansions ?

3- Since the apps running on the server will be using a directory located on the raid partition, once i am out of storage, is it necessary to add 2 physical disks to expand the existing raid 1 and set the new 2 disks to raid 1 too ? what are the proper and safest steps to add those disks (while keeping the old ones, and without replacing them with larger ones) using mdadm or lvextend (in case of lvm config).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there's only one proper solution to you problem, but here's what I usually do:

- If possible, keep your OS/Boot Media separate from your RAID used for general storage. I'm not familiar with Dell server hardware or the RAID controller used, but I would suggest using dedicated hard drives for the OS (be it on the same RAID controler or not). Keep in mind, that this could be a potential single point of failure.
- When building your RAID, I would suggest to use the volume exported by the controler as a PV in LVM. This way, you can add drives to your existing RAID, expand your LVM setup and grow the filesystem underneath.
- Regarding expanding your RAID1: You should check the documentation of the specific controller. Some let you "migrate" your RAID to lager sizes when swaping out your hard drives for larger ones. In this case, again, LVM is very helpful in expanding your filesystems.

Regaring booting your system off of /boot within LVM: I'm not 100% certain about this, so I'm not going to answer this just to be sure.